# Node js express js proxy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

[Here is an image of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxdlu.png) I developed an application on AngularJS, and when I run node server by using public wifi my application is running fine. However, when I run it on org network/company wifi my application doesn't work. Any help?

**server.js code**

```
var express = require("express");
var open = require("open");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var auth = require("./api/auth");
//var users = require("./api/users");
var transactions = require("./api/transactions");
//var serviceTypes = require("./api/serviceTypes");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static("boilerplate"));
app.use(express.static("./"));

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("server is running on port:3000");
open("http://localhost:3000/");
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "boilerplate/index.html"));
});

app.use("/auth", auth);
//app.use("/users", users);
app.use("/transactions", transactions);
//app.use("/servicetypes", serviceTypes);
```

Comment: Use developer tools to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).